# Load PDF into UIImage or UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiimageview, uiimage, iphone-sdk-3.2

I'm trying to load a PDF file stored in Resources into a UIImage/UIImageView object in the iPhone SDK. Is this at all possible without converting the PDF to an image? If not, what are the member functions for converting a PDF into a PNG? I would really prefer to preserve the PDF if at all pssoible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDFs can be loaded by UIWebView.  If you need more control you can use Quartz 2D to render PDFs: [Quartz2D](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101)

Comment: Are there any built in functions to translate a PDF document into a PNG?

Comment: I haven't tried it but you could try using quartz 2d to CGImageRef then create a UIImage with that ref then try using UIImagePNGRepresentation.  Again, never tried it.

Answer (score 11):

Now it is possible, I am using iOS 8+.
If you put a pdf in your assets catalog, and then load the pdf in a UIImage using `[UIImage imageNamed:]` it renders the first page of the pdf into the UIImage.

Comment: it is not rendering a pdf. The Asset catalog breaks out the pdf to pngs for each scale size at build time.

Comment: @maxpower is correct, during build time xcode breaks the pdf vector into relevant images. If you have a pdf file that is inside the document folder and NOT the asset catalog you may want to use Tony Lenzi's answer

Comment: Things are a bit different for iOS11+ https://useyourloaf.com/blog/xcode-9-vector-images/

Answer (score 6):

You may want to check out this UIImage-PDF category over on GitHub: https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF

Answer (score 3):

a solution based on 'https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-render-a-pdf-to-an-image'

```
//MARK: - für Bild vom PDF erstellen
extension SettingsQuellen{
func drawIMGfromPDF(thisPDF: String) -> UIImage? {

    ///holt das PDF aus einem Verzeichnis im Programm
    ///nicht aus der 'Assets.xcassets'

    let path = Bundle.main.path(
        forResource: thisPDF,  //"fsm75-3 (Startstrecke)"
        ofType     : "pdf")  /////path to local file

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    //following based on: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/core-graphics/how-to-render-a-pdf-to-an-image

    guard let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL) else { return nil }
    guard let page = document.page(at: 1) else { return nil }

    let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        UIColor.white.set()
        ctx.fill(pageRect)

        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
    }

    return img
}//end func drawIMGfromPDF
}//end extension SettingsQuellen - für Bild vom PDF erstellen
```

Usage:

```
let img = drawIMGfromPDF(thisPDF: "fsm75-3 (Startstrecke)") //Bild vom PDF erstellen
cell.outletImageView.image = img
```

Answer (score 2):

for **`Swift`**,

> just `Import` or `Add` your **`PDF`** to `Assets` and use it like
>   below.
>
> `your_image_view.image = UIImage(named:"name_of_your_file")`
>
> that is it and this should work charmly

Answer (score 1):

for Swift,
just Import or Add your PDF to Assets and use it like below.

```
your_image_view.image = UIImage(named:"name_of_your_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code blow. This code is the similar the other answers. The trick is UIColor.clear.set() instead of UIColor.white.set() line. If you use white background will be white.

```js
func drawPDFfromURL(url: URL) - > UIImage ? {
  guard
  let document = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL)
  else {
    return nil
  }
  guard
  let page = document.page(at: 1)
  else {
    return nil
  }

  let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
  let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
  let img = renderer.image {
    ctx in
      UIColor.clear.set()
    ctx.fill(pageRect)

    ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
    ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
  }

  return img
}
```